# How do I send data from sensors using a Raspberry Pi over WiFi to a webpage?

Tags: pi-3, sensor, wireless, php, razberry

So far I have the code that reads the distance using the razbery pi sensor, but how can I do the rest? if anyone can help me with a tutorial so I can understand, I'm new and I don't really understand all the terms.
The site where I want to display is made in php

Comment: Your question is a bit off-topic for Raspberry Pi because it's really a coding question and not a question about the Raspberry Pi.  In any case, there isn't enough information to be able to answer the question.

Presumably you've got some code that reads data from your sensor, but we don't know what programming language is being used.  From there, we also don't know what interfaces are available on your target server.  For example, does it have ReST API's that can be called to send the data?  ReST API's are independent of programming language.

Comment: is the pi hosting the page or does it report to a server elsewhere?  Also what is this code in? C? python? shell script?